# Some of my texture not showing up

Tags: texturing, texture-painting

I started editing and importing a texture file and so far its been working fine, however I started editing the arms, which are apart of the same texture file, but it just didn't work, I tried messing around in paint editer but the arms and legs aren't affected; I tried doing an orange squiggle on paint.net with them but they just don't plainly show up.

https://www.mediafire.com/folder/giujb9qrhou13/Iron_Golem

That Folder has my model and my texture.

Answer (score 2):

You've assigned the legs and arms to a slot that is completely empty, no material for the moment:

[image]

If you plan to assign them the same material as the body, keep legs and arms selected, select the first slot (with *Material*) and click on *Assign*:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked like a charm, turns out I'm just stupid.